# Shankar Quantum Question about Infinite Square Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, normalization

I'm reading Shankar's Quantum Mechanics Book and on page 159 he says after solving for the symmetrical box potential's coefficients $A$ and $B$ that because we have $$A=(-1)^{n+1}B$$ for $$\Psi=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$$ that we have the solutions $$\Psi=\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})\ \ \ n \ even $$ $$\Psi=\cos(\frac{n \pi x}{L})\ \ \ n \ odd $$ But I don't understand how to get these equations mathematically from our initial fact about $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n=even, $A = -B$ so you have $\Psi=A[e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}]$ which is nothing but $2Asin(kx)$ where $k=\frac{n \pi }{L}$ Similarly for n=odd you have $A=B$ and $\Psi=A[e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}]$ and $2Acos(kx)$.

edit: This follows from [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

Comment: Shouldn't that be $2Aisin(kx)$ though? That is what is confusing me

Comment: Ah yes. The constants don't matter since you'll normalize the wavefunction anyways.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't realize that until now. Thank you!